# Styling mat-radio-button in Angular Material

Tags: angular-material, angular7

I have just started using the Angular Material theme within my Angular app.

I make use of some radio buttons but want to style them so that they are smaller than usual. I can style the text labels but I am struggling to style the actual buttons themselves (the circles).

So for now, I have

```
<mat-radio-group class="smallRadio">
    <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

How should I go about that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this,

Default radius is `20px` we are setting it to `10px` here

```css
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-container{
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-outer-circle{
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-inner-circle{
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-button .mat-radio-ripple{
      height: 20px; /*double of your required circle radius*/
      width: 20px;  /*double of your required circle radius*/
      left: calc(50% - 10px); /*'10px'-same as your required circle radius*/
      top: calc(50% - 10px); /*'10px'-same as your required circle radius*/
    }
```

**Without using `::ng-deep`**

Turn off encapsulation of your component inside which you use the custom radio.

You can do this by

```js
import {Component,ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: 'example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['example.component.css'],
  encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class ExampleComponent {}
```

Wrap the component you want to style in a custom class.So it wont affect any other radio components.
In the above question its already wrapped with `smallRadio` class

```css
.smallRadio .mat-radio-container{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
.smallRadio .mat-radio-outer-circle{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
.smallRadio .mat-radio-inner-circle{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
.smallRadio .mat-radio-button .mat-radio-ripple{
    height: 20px; 
    width: 20px; 
    left: calc(50% - 10px); 
    top: calc(50% - 10px); 
}
```

You can add these css in global stylesheet without turning off view encapsulation. But more elegant method is the above one

Comment: I believe the :ng-deep feature is deprecated and will stop working at some point, what's the right way to style a button in Angular 8 and beyond?

Comment: Hi @chrisinmtown. I had updated the answer. Check  [customising angular material components](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles) for more.

Answer (score 13):

Please do **not** use `ViewEncapsulation.None` in your project. In future it will lead to unpredictable behavior. When you change styles inside one component some other components can be changed as well and it will be difficult to find which ones.

If you want to override styles of angular material I suggest creating a separate *.scss in your project with the name like `"material-overrides.scss"` where you will put all style changes for different components.
For example, your file can look like this

```
example-component {
    .smallRadio .mat-radio-container{
      height: 10px !important;
      width: 10px !important;
    }
    .smallRadio .mat-radio-outer-circle{
        height: 10px !important;
        width: 10px !important;
    }
    .smallRadio .mat-radio-inner-circle{
        height: 10px !important;
        width: 10px !important;
    }
    .smallRadio .mat-radio-button .mat-radio-ripple{
        height: 20px !important; 
        width: 20px !important; 
        left: calc(50% - 10px) !important; 
        top: calc(50% - 10px) !important; 
    }
}
```

Please pay attention to `!important` in my example. It's also not a good practice. You need to replace it with more precise specifity [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Please also do not forget to add your created `material-overrides.scss` file to `styles.scss` like that:

```
@import './material-overrides.scss';
```

You can also read recommendations for overrides from angular material team - [link](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles).

Answer (score 9):

I think, this should be enough:

```
.mat-radio-container {
    transform: scale(0.85);
}
```

Choose the number in the scale according to your needs.

Comment: as we can apply the css property directly on mat-radio-button element ;)

Comment: The problem I found with this is the ripple effect (when clicking) is still the original size so it looks offset from the newly scaled `.mat-radio-container`

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**
I've got it working with a tick, changing css

```css
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-outer-circle{
      border-radius:2px;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-inner-circle{
        border-radius:2px;
        background-color: transparent!important;
        border-bottom: 4px solid white;
        border-right:4px solid white;
        height:30px;  
        width:15px;
        margin-top: -8px;
       margin-left: 3px;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle{
       background:#ff4081!important;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-inner-circle{
       transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
    }
 
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-button .mat-radio-ripple{
      height: 20px; /*double of your required circle radius*/
      width: 20px;  /*double of your required circle radius*/
      left: calc(50% - 10px); /*'10px'-same as your required circle radius*/
      top: calc(50% - 10px); /*'10px'-same as your required circle radius */
    }
```