# How to make mat-checkbox like a radio button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-checkbox in the angular project. How to make a mat-checkbox can only be selected one. (No more than one). Here's the code I have:

```
<mat-checkbox>Pre Order</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox>Order</mat-checkbox>
```

Can anyone help? I want the mat-checkbox to behave like a mat-radio-button.

Comment: I would recommend using the mat-radio-button for such functionality and change the style to look like a checkbox by using css/scss.

Comment: @KingDarBoja Thank you for the solution. But I have difficulty in changing the css mat-radio-button to be like a mat-checkbox

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892268/styling-mat-radio-button-in-angular-material/53893229

Comment: @KingDarBoja This method only makes the mat-radio-button look smaller than the standard. Not changing shape :(

Comment: Set `border-radius: 0%;` for `.mat-radio-outer-circle` and that's it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get the correct answer:

1. Use the mat-radio-button
2. Set `border-radius: 0%;` for `.mat-radio-outer-circle` css class

And that's it!

Cheers!

Comment: This only makes the radio button box shaped like a checkbox, not the checkbox selection. This would still need to look like a check mark which can be done through css. Also the ripple animation needs to match.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to make a transparent radio button control part and draw a checkbox control element instead.
The checkbox is a state recipient and should not be clicked.
Angular 17 code:

```js
    allItems: Array<Item> = [{name: 'name1'} as any, {name: 'name2'} as any];

    onItemSelected(model: Item) {
        const items = this.allItems;
        if (items) {
            for (const item of items) {
                (item as any).selected = false;
            }
        }
        if (model) {
            (model as any).selected = true;
        }
    }
```

```css
:host ::ng-deep .mdc-radio {
    opacity: 0;
}
:host ::ng-deep mat-checkbox {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<mat-checkbox
    (click)="$event.preventDefault()"
    [ngModel]="$any(item).selected">
</mat-checkbox>
<mat-radio-button class="mt-1 mx-1 name"
    [value]="$any(item).selected"
    (change)="onItemSelected(item)">{{ item.name }}
</mat-radio-button>
```