# How to style a Mat radio-button to look like a checkbox

Tags: angular, radio-button

When the radio button is checked, I want to indicate that with a tick(line checkbox) instead of a dot.

```
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="row.selected">
      <mat-radio-button  class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of texts"
                      [checked]="false" [value]="season.Answer_Id">
                      <span class="answer"> {{season.Text}} </span>
      </mat-radio-button>
 </mat-radio-group>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!!
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892268/styling-mat-radio-button-in-angular-material/53893229 
May be this could help you!..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143309/how-to-make-mat-checkbox-like-a-radio-button
Check this too..

Comment: Hi @AnglesvarCheenu, I checked that out already, I can't change from dot to tick